# Deploying SharePoint files (css, javascript) onto different platforms without SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, css

I need to deploy to "_catalogs/masterpage/" and "Style Library/" multiple jpg, css, javascript files These files originate from a developer platform and are to be deployed to multiple platforms without using SharePoint Designer. Apart from manually uploading multiple files in the /Forms/AllItems.aspx pages, is there another way to do this ?

I'm using SharePoint 2007

Comment: Build a WSP file which will add the files and deploy that?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to deploy these kind of components is via a .wsp package, which are created when "Packaging" a Visual Studio solution. For SharePoint 2007 you would need Visual Studio 2008.

Basically, you need:
. Visual Studio 2008
. WSPBuilder (optional add-in which makes life much easier)
. Create a mapped Layouts folder and add the javascript and css files
. Create a module with the masterpage that deploys to the master page gallery

Here's a link with pretty good step by step on how to achieve this:
[developing-sharepoint-solutions-in-visual-studio](http://www.greggalipeau.com/2008/05/18/developing-sharepoint-solutions-in-visual-studio/).

Comment: While it's true that Visual Studio will help you, you can also build yourself the wsp files. It's actually a cab file with another extension that describes what is to be deployed. If there is no code, only file deployment, this can be a viable solution.

Comment: Great addition...